# Change original array values in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays that contain array key with the value, here the example :

```
 $text = [
         [
         0 => ['Andi', 'NOB', false],
         1 => ['menginap', 'V', false],
         2 => ['di', 'PREP', false],
         3 => ['Hotel', 'N', false],
         4 => ['Neo', 'NE', false],
         5 => ['Malioboro', 'NE', false],
         6 => ['selama', 'N', false],
         7 => ['satu', 'NUM', false],
         8 => ['minggu', 'N',false]
        ]
    ];
```

and I also have this array :

```
$flag = [3,4,5,6];
```

Now, If flag element array is on text key then I will change third element from false to true.

For example :
$flag[0] = 3, then I will change text with key 3 to :

```
[3] = > 'Hotel', 'N', true
```

Here's what I am doing for the moment:

```
foreach($text as $index => &$tok){
    foreach ($tok as $tokkey => &$tokvalue) {
        foreach($flag as $key => $value){
           if($value == $tokkey){
               $tokvalue[2] = true;
           }
        }
   }
}
```

But, it didn't change everything.
Any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

try it,it'll work for you:

```
$text = [
        [
            '0' => 'Andi,NOB,false',
            '1' => 'menginap,V,false',
            '2' => 'di,PREP,false',
            '3' => 'Hotel,N,false',
            '4' => 'Neo,NE,false',
            '5' => 'Malioboro,NE,false',
            '6' => 'selama,N,false',
            '7' => 'satu,NUM,false',
            '8' => 'minggu,N,false'
        ]
        ];
$flag = [3,4,5,6] ;

foreach($text as $k=> $value){
foreach($flag as $key=> $val){
       $kk[] = explode(',',$value[$val]);
       $kk[$key][2] = 'true';
       $kkk[] = implode(',',$kk[$key]);
}
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($kkk);
```

to print the array which we want to change false value to true value.

the below code for showing all data with replacing for required output:

```
$text = [
        [
            ['Andi', 'NOB', 'false'],
            ['menginap', 'V', 'false'],
            ['di', 'PREP', 'false'],
            ['Hotel', 'N', 'false'],
            ['Neo', 'NE', 'false'],
            ['Malioboro', 'NE', 'false'],
            ['selama', 'N', 'false'],
            ['satu', 'NUM', 'false'],
            ['minggu', 'N.', 'false']
        ]
        ];

$flag = [3,4,5,6];

foreach ($text as $k => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $kk => $val) {
            foreach ($flag as $key) {
                if ($key == $kk)
                    $text[$k][$kk][2] = 'true';
            }
        }
}

 echo '<pre>'; print_r($text);
```

Comment: This answer uses unadvisable coding practice because (unless every element is in the subarray is to be set to `true`) this method will be doing a number of useless iterations.

Answer (score 2):

This might help.

```
foreach($text as $index => &$tok){
    foreach ($tok as $tokkey => &$tokvalue) {
        foreach($flag as $key => $value){
           if($value == $tokkey){
               $val = explode(",",$tokvalue);
               $val[2] = true;
               $tokvalue = implode(",",$val);
           }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer uses unadvisable coding practice because (unless every element is in the subarray is to be set to `true`) this method will be doing a number of useless iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Here we are using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to achieve desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/856714)

```
array_walk($text[0],function(&$value,$key) use($flag){
     if(in_array($key, $flag)){ // checking whether the $key is present in the flag array
        $value[2]=true;//change the $value second index to true
     }
});
```

Comment: This answer uses unadvisable coding practice because (unless every element is in the subarray is to be set to `true`) this method will be doing a number of useless iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this would be array,

```
$text = [
    0 => ['Andi', 'NOB', false],
    1 => ['menginap', 'V', false],
    2 => ['di', 'PREP', false],
    3 => ['Hotel', 'N', false],
    4 => ['Neo', 'NE', false],
    5 => ['Malioboro', 'NE', false],
    6 => ['selama', 'N', false],
    7 => ['satu', 'NUM', false],
    8 => ['minggu', 'N.',false],
];
$flag = [0 => 3, 1 => 4, 2 => 5, 3 => 6];
foreach ($text as $key => &$value) {
    if(in_array($key, $flag)){
        $value[2] = true;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($text);
```

Please check output [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b8aaf69e8460081ffd0d3d4c0288da4df6e738a)

Comment: This answer uses unadvisable coding practice because (unless every element is in the subarray is to be set to `true`) this method will be doing a number of useless iterations.

Answer (score 1):

how about directly accessing the `$text`?

```
$text[$index][$tokkey][2] = true;
```

this way you don't need to use references.

```
$text = [
  [
    ['Andi', 'NOB', false],
    ['menginap', 'V', false],
    ['di', 'PREP', false],
    ['Hotel', 'N', false],
    ['Neo', 'NE', false],
    ['Malioboro', 'NE', false],
    ['selama', 'N', false],
    ['satu', 'NUM', false],
    ['minggu', 'N.', false]
  ]
];

$flag = [3,4,5,6];

foreach ($text as $index => $token) { // outer list
  foreach ($token as $i => $t) { //inner list
    foreach ($flag as $key) {
      if ($key == $i)
        $text[$index][$i][2] = true;
    }
  }
}

print_r($text);
```

Comment: This answer uses unadvisable coding practice because (unless every element is in the subarray is to be set to `true`) this method will be doing a number of useless iterations.

Answer (score 1):

And I'll put my two cents in as well:

```
foreach($flag as $key){
    $text[0][$key][2] = true;
}
```

[Code snippet here](https://eval.in/856737)

Answer (score 1):

There is no cleaner / more direct (error-proof) way than:

**Code**: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/610b9e40c819f8c1eb7bc73da93f42a58bdb6649)) THE SIMPLEST WAY

```
$flag=3; // index 
if(isset($text[0][$flag][2])){$text[0][$flag][2]=true;}  // make sure the element exists
```

If you have multiple flags:

```
$flags=[3,6,7]; // indices 
foreach($flags as $flag){
   if(isset($text[0][$flag][2])){$text[0][$flag][2]=true;}  // make sure the element exists
}
```

---

Any method that is looping your `$text` array is at risk of running useless iterations.  This would be inefficient / poor coding practice.

Comment: If the `$flags` array is generated from user input or some other unreliable source, then it is possible that a non-existent index will be provided and cause an warning/notice.  By using `isset()` I eliminate this possibility.  This is why I say "error-proof"  If `$flags` is from a trustworthy source, then the condition can be removed -- that is for the OP to determine.  It is better to teach the safe way and remove as needed.

Comment: If there are unsuccessful iterations in my method, it is because of a user error.  All methods that are iterating `$text` will iterate the full array regardless of how many flags there are.  This is the logic to understand/implement/teach.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array of flags and equate the those keys value with the array of your required values.

```
$flag = [1,3];

$text = [
    0 => ['a', 'x', true],
    1 => ['a', 'y', false],
    2 => ['x', 'd', true],
    3 => ['x', 's', true],
    4 => ['a', 'x', false],
];

foreach ($flag as $key) {
    if (isset($text[$key])) {
        $text[$key][2] = true;
    }
}
```

[Solution fiddle](https://ideone.com/ZAf4I5)

Comment: This answer has now been edited to exactly replicate my method, but is not using the input array data/structure that the OP has provided.  If you found my answer useful, you may upvote it.